# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n, \; \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n,$ are positive and diverge, prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \max(a_n,b_n)$ diverges

Tags: calculus, summation

I'm struggling with the following question:

Given that both $\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n, \;\; \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n, \;$ are positive and diverge, prove that: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \max(a_n,b_n)$$

also diverges.

Comment: The partial sums are bounded below by the partial sums of the original sums. Note:  I think you meant the upper indices for your sums to be $\infty$.

Comment: It is enough to require only one of the series is divergent, as the answer belows remarks, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that  $a_n\leq max(a_n,b_n$), so when $\sum a_n$ is diverage then $\sum max(a_n,b_n)$ is diverage.

Comment: The word you may be looking for is "divergent", not "diverage". +1